# Custom UIButton class not centered horizontally

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, storyboard, viewcontroller

I created a custom button class that overrides the default button appearance in Xcode.  I assigned the class of my existing storyboard buttons to the new custom class and everything looks fine except the buttons are no longer centered horizontally.  I'm new to coding in Swift and would greatly appreciate help with this.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Here's the custom button class code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    let radius: CGFloat = 40
    
    let darkGreen: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(23)/CGFloat(255),
                                     green: CGFloat(165)/CGFloat(255),
                                     blue: CGFloat(137)/CGFloat(255),
                                     alpha: 1)
    
    let lightGreen: UIColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(112)/CGFloat(255),
                                     green: CGFloat(232)/CGFloat(255),
                                     blue: CGFloat(100)/CGFloat(255),
                                     alpha: 1)

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupButton()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupButton()
    }

    lazy var gradient: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.type = .axial
        gradient.colors = [darkGreen.cgColor, lightGreen.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        gradient.cornerRadius = radius
        return gradient
    }()

    func setupButton() {
        frame.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 80)
        tintColor = .white
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        gradient.frame = bounds
        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```

Comment: Setup constraints

Comment: I added the following constraints to the view controller but it didn't center the button, `mapButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true`

Comment: I changed the constraints to `mapButton.center = view.center` which worked, but now the buttons are both overlapping in the center of the screen, so looks like I'll need to find a way to assign y-position constraints for each button.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code to the viewController allowed me to horizontally center the button and also assign the vertical position:

```
mapButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height/2.75)
```